# Redis adapter - Cluster de socket.io, Failed to refresh slots cache en node.js

Tags: nodejs, typescript, socket.io, redis, redis-adapter

**CASO DE USO:** tengo dos servidores backend en node.js el cual ya tengo implementado y funcionando socket.io y además tengo configurado **REDIS** para comunicación entre servidores, muestro como es el código de ambos servidores por efecto de simplicidad solo muestro 1 de los dos servidores pero los cambios son mínimos

```
import express from 'express';
import http from 'http';
import { Server as SocketIOServer } from 'socket.io';
import { createAdapter } from '@socket.io/redis-adapter';
import { createClient } from 'redis';

const PORT = 3000;

const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = new SocketIOServer(server);

// Crear el cliente de Redis
const pubClient = createClient({ url: 'redis://localhost:6379' });
const subClient = pubClient.duplicate();

(async () => {
    await pubClient.connect();
    await subClient.connect();
})();

// Configurar el adaptador de Redis
io.adapter(createAdapter(pubClient, subClient));

pubClient.on('connect', () => console.log('::> Redis Client Connected'));
pubClient.on('error', (err) => console.log('<:: CLIENTE REDIS ERROR: ', err));

subClient.on('connect', () => { console.log('::> Redis subClient Connected'); });

// recibir mensaje de otro servidor socket
subClient.subscribe('mensajeCanal', (message: any, canal: any) => {
    console.log('MENSAJE DESDE OTRO SERVER: ', JSON.parse(message));
});

app.get('/', (req: any, res: any) => {
    res.send('¡Hola, mundo!');
});

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log('Usuario conectado');
    socket.on('message', (message: any) => {
        console.log(`Mensaje recibido: ${message}`);

        // Puedes emitir el mensaje de vuelta a todos los clientes conectados
        io.emit('message', 'respuesta del servidor');

        // Emitir el mensaje a otro servidor
        pubClient.publish('mensajeCanal', JSON.stringify(message));
        // pubClient.publish('mensajeCanal2', "otro mensaje");
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        console.log('Usuario desconectado');
    });
});

// Escuchar en el puerto después de configurar todo
server.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Servidor escuchando en el puerto ${PORT}`);
});
```

ejecuto tsc -w, luego

```
node dist/index
```

y me conecto exitosamente entre servidores utilizando redis

pero nesesito implementar **CLUSTER en REDIS** para tener alta disponibilida, y para ello he levantado dos servidores redis en docker

```
# Levantar el primer servidor Redis en el puerto 6379
docker run --name redis-node1 -p 6379:6379 -d redis

# Levantar el segundo servidor Redis en el puerto 6380
docker run --name redis-node2 -p 6380:6379 -d redis
```

hice pruebas en ambas y me respondieron correctamente

ahora ocupe el código de la documentación oficial: [socket.io/redis-adapter](https://socket.io/docs/v4/redis-adapter/)

```
import { Server } from "socket.io";
import { createAdapter } from "@socket.io/redis-adapter";
import { Cluster } from "ioredis";

const io = new Server();

const pubClient = new Cluster([
  {
    host: "localhost",
    port: 6379,
  },
  {
    host: "localhost",
    port: 6380,
  },
]);

const subClient = pubClient.duplicate();

io.adapter(createAdapter(pubClient, subClient));
pubClient.on('error', (err: any) => console.log('<:: CLIENTE REDIS ERROR: ', err));

io.listen(3000);
```

y cuando lo pruebo me da el siguiente mensaje

```
 <:: CLIENTE REDIS ERROR: ClusterAllFailedError: Failed to refresh slots cache.
    at tryNode (C:\path\test_server\node_modules\ioredis\built\cluster\index.js:308:31)
    at C:\path\test_server\node_modules\ioredis\built\cluster\index.js:325:21
    at C:\path\test_server\node_modules\ioredis\built\cluster\index.js:662:24
    at run (C:\path\test_server\node_modules\ioredis\built\utils\index.js:117:22)
    at tryCatcher (C:\path\test_server\node_modules\standard-as-callback\built\utils.js:12:23)
    at C:\path\test_server\node_modules\standard-as-callback\built\index.js:33:51
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5) {
  lastNodeError: ReplyError: ERR This instance has cluster support disabled
      at parseError (C:path\test_server\node_modules\redis-parser\lib\parser.js:179:12)
      at parseType (C:path\test_server\node_modules\redis-parser\lib\parser.js:302:14) {
    command: { name: 'cluster', args: [Array] }
  }
}
```

los puertos que estoy usando son: 6379 y 6380, ademas estoy utilizando typeScript y ambos servidores estan funcionando.

Comment: al parecer te faltaria el paso de crear el cluster q es donde se definen y reparten los hash slots entre todos los redis involucrados

Comment: no tengo idea de como hacer eso ¿me puedes orientar donde lo debo de hacer?

Comment: https://redis.io/docs/management/scaling/#create-a-redis-cluster es onda desde el terminal de uno de los contenedores de una de las instancias, algo tipo `redis-cli --cluster create [...listadeips:puertos] --cluster-replicas 1` usando docker maybe necesitas crear un subnetwork para q se vean entre ellos (cada node/instancia), en algun momento le pruebo a ver si sale simple